# If I pass this code in Windows console it works, but when I emulate windows console in node.js code doesn't work, and returns unclear error

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, ffmpeg, trim

I have code:

```
cmd.get(
    'trimp3  ant.mp3 ant2.mp3 00:00 00:20',
    function(data){
        console.log('the node-cmd cloned dir contains these files :\n\n',data)
    }
);
```

If pass this code in Windows console it works well!
But, when i emulate windows console in node.js this code not work, and returns unclear mistake:

```
[!!] ERROR:  "ffmpeg" �� ����� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� �������� 䠩���.
```

To emulate the use node-cmd.

Answer (score 0):

you are likely in the wrong directory.

try something like :

```
cmd.get(
    'trimp3  /full/path/to/ant.mp3 ant2.mp3 00:00 00:20',
    function(data){
        console.log('node-cmd output:\n\n',data)
    }
);
```

or

```
cmd.get(
    `
    cd /path/to/files/
    trimp3  ant.mp3 ant2.mp3 00:00 00:20
    `,
    function(data){
        console.log('node-cmd output:\n\n',data)
    }
);
```